# Phonegap navigation bar moves with page scroll

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I am entirely new to Phonegap. I am using [iconicframework](http://ionicframework.com) to build the UI of my app. Now i am facing a problem. When i scroll the page my navigation bar also scrolls with the page I noticed that it only happens when keyboard comes in.

My **config.xml**

```
<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.3.0" />
<feature name="StatusBar">
  <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true" />
</feature>
```

***What i did so far.*** 
1. Added keyboard plugin as suggested in an answer

Check the images. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Add the keyboard plugin to your project:

`cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.keyboard`

And add the following setting to your `config.xml`:

`<preference name="KeyboardShrinksView" value="true"/>`

Answer (score 0):

What version of ionic are you using? You should try beta 4 and install our forked version of cordova's keyboard plugin.

```
$ cordova plugin add https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugins-keyboard.git
```

Also, check out [this post](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/chat-tutorial-using-beta3-epic/3848), which is an in depth look at the keyboard plugin. We're hoping to get a block post out about the keyboard soon!

[You can get the plugin here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugins-keyboard)